# Set time zone issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to set the time zone of my website to Europe/Brussels.
I've made a small php file:

```
<?php
$DT = new DateTime($timestamp,new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$DT->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Brussels'));
$date = $DT->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

I've included this file in all other php files. 
The issue I"m having is that I put a timestamp on my mysql.
Than in an other file I'm calling this timestamp with a prepared statement PDO.
But even that I set the new default time on each page that I'm using the date doesn't get adjust.

As I can't change the timezone on mysql due to restrictions of my provider they advised me to use the above script. But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question and flatten `$timestamp` with an actual timestamp and then post what you are getting from `var_export($date);` and what you are expecting.

Comment: The "above script" is just a suggestion. That is just setting the timezone for that one instance of the DateTime class, not globally in any way. What they are suggesting is anywhere you use a date, instantiate that date into a DateTime object and then set your timezone of choice. It isn't something you would include in all files.

Answer (score 1):

You may have changed your default timezone in PHP, but you need to change it for your mysql as well. Timestamps generated in MySQL will be based on the timezone set for MySQL.

Here's an example of how synchronize your MySQL timezone with your PHP timezone:

```
<?php
$now = new DateTime();
$mins = $now->getOffset() / 60;
$sgn = ($mins < 0 ? -1 : 1);
$mins = abs($mins);
$hrs = floor($mins / 60);
$mins -= $hrs * 60;
$offset = sprintf('%+d:%02d', $hrs*$sgn, $mins);

//Your DB Connection - sample
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
$db->exec("SET time_zone='$offset';");
```

Comment: Can I include this in the time.php file and than included it in all my other php files? Or how do I go about this?

Comment: @WouterS It depends what you want to do. Usually its good practise to not change your default timezone of your database too much so that old timestamps in database entries are not affected by changes.

Comment: @WouterS if you are only ever dealing with the timezone `Europe/Brussels` it might be a good idea to set the database to that once and never change it. If you have users in multiple timezones, I would suggest setting the database timezone to something like `UTC` and then make any adjustments to the returned time based on the user viewing it.

Comment: it doesn't matter that old data is messed up. Still testing data inside. But I've this made a file called `time.php` and included the above code. ofcourse with my db credentials. On each of the php files that I used I `include ('time.php);'`...but the time on my server is still running 2 hours behind my time

Comment: The only thing that matters is my time zone. The timestamp is for me to use only....And who do I set the default time to `Europe/Brussels` once and never to change it?

Comment: @WouterS you can update it with the query `SET time_zone = 'Europe/Brussels';`

Comment: So I did `$db->exec("SET time_zone='Europe/Brussels';");` in my `time.php`. I than `include ('time.php');` on each of my php pages....but still the wrong time...what am I doing wrong?